# Classifying spaces of algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, classifying-spaces

I am working on Fabien Morel's paper : "A1-Algebraic topology over a field" and I am a bit confused about certains properties of classifying spaces.

For example  : How to show that $BSL_r \longrightarrow BGL_r$ is a $G_m$-torsor?

Here $BGL_r$ and $BSL_r$ are living in the $A^1$-homotopy category of schemes over a field.

Comment: hint : this is the pull-back of the universal $BG_m$ torsor via $Bdet: BGL_r\to BG_m$.

Comment: More concretely, given a scheme $S$ and a map $S\to BGL_r$--equivalently, a vector bundle $V$ over $S$ of constant rank $r$--the fiber-product $S\times_{BGL_r}BSL_r$ is precisely the scheme over $S$ that parameterizes trivializations of the determinant line bundle $\wedge^{r}V$. This latter space is clearly a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor over $S$.